# glReadPixels does not read cursor

Tags: macos, cursor, screen, buffer

I am developing and Mac-Desktop application in which I am reading the screen buffer data and create image out of it.
I use the call 'glReadPixels' to read the screen data.

The problem is that when the screen is zoomed, the screen data includes the cursor in it and hence the cursor is included in the image created out of this buffer. But, I do not want to show this cursor image in it.

Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Deepa